# Google Youtube API watch later

Tags: php, youtube, google-api

I would like to get all my youtube watch later video list whith PHP API 3.0 but it seem's that we can not access to these with PHP and API 3. Does anyone have done it yet ?

My code for now

```
// Call the YouTube Data API's channelSections.list method to retrieve your channel sections.
$listResponse = $youtube->channelSections->listChannelSections('snippet,contentDetails', array('mine' => true));
$channelSections = $listResponse['items'];

$htmlBody .= "<h2>Sections Shuffled</h2><ul>";

foreach ($channelSections as $channelSection) {
  // Each section in the list of shuffled sections is sequentially
  // set to position 0, i.e. the top.
  $channelSection['snippet']['position'] = 0;

  // Call the YouTube Data API's channelSections.update method to update a channel section.
  $updateResponse = $youtube->channelSections->update('snippet,contentDetails', $channelSection);

  $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s "%s"</li>',
      $updateResponse['id'], $updateResponse['snippet']['title']);
}

$htmlBody .= '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$youtube->channels->listChannels` instead of `$youtube->channelSections->listChannelSections`

```
// Get all channels of current user
$channels = $youtube->channels->listChannels('contentDetails', ['mine' => true]);

// Get watch later playlists ID from the first channel
$watchLaterListId = $channels[0]->getContentDetails()->getRelatedPlaylists()->getWatchLater();

// Get videos from the playlist
$videos = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('contentDetails', ['playlistId' => $watchLaterListId]);

// Loop videos
foreach($videos as $video)
{
    // This is the global video ID.
    $globalVideoId = $video->getContentDetails()->getVideoId();

    // This is unique ID of this video on the playlist. The one you need to interact with the playlist
    $playlistVideoId = $video->id;

    //i.e: To remove this video from the playlist
    $youtube->playlistItems->delete($playlistVideoId);
}
```